# Simple Cypher Program Not Working (CS50)

Tags: cs50

On week 2 of CS50 and I've hit a wall. My code is supposed to prompt a user for plaintext and then print a simple cypher on the next line. Problem is, my code keeps printing the exact input for the user rather than scrambling. My code is below.

Note: the error in my code is likely down in the for loop, inside the respective printf functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[]){
    if (argc != 2){
        printf("You must enter two arguments, the second being a single digit integer!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int key = atoi(argv[1]);

    printf("What do you want to encrpyt?");
    string s = get_string();


    for(int i=0; i < strlen(s); i++){

       if (isupper(s[i])==true){
       printf("%c",((s[i] + key)));
       }

       if (islower(s[i])==true){
       printf("%c",s[i] + key);
       }

       else {
           printf("%c",s[i]);
       }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The if statement syntax was wrong, so the program was skipping over the cypher text. I need to delete the "==true" out of the if statement.